How to prove that the sequence $a_n=\lfloor r \rfloor + \frac{\lfloor (r- \lfloor r \rfloor) \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}$ converges to $r$?
By formal defintion i have tried $$|a_n-r|=|\lfloor r \rfloor + \frac{\lfloor (r- \lfloor r \rfloor) \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}-r|$$
I was thinking of using the inequality $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$ but the absolute value sign is making it difficult.

Hint: what is the the thing added to $\lfloor r\rfloor$? Try to show that it is decimal representation of first $n$ digits of $r$ after the decimal point.

Hint: $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, use that for the numerator of the fraction.

why the downvotes?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

The classic proof of the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ gives the result, ie. using the inequality $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$.
$$
x-10^{-n} < \frac{\lfloor x \times10^n\rfloor}{10^n} \leq x,
$$
therefore by the squeeze theorem, the middle term tends to $x$. This result can be applied to your case with $x = r -\lfloor r \rfloor$.
Edit: As an additional insight, the sequence represents the decimal cutoffs of $r$. Meaning that if $r = \pi$ then
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 3 \\
a_1 &= 3.1 \\
a_2 &= 3.14 \\
a_3 &= 3.141 \\
a_3 &= 3.1415 \\
\text{etc}& \ldots \\
a_n &\to \pi
\end{align}

Thank you!! i forgot about squeeze, this works fine!!
